# How to create a button that slides out when the mouse hovers over it? (Unity2D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, 2d, mouseover, slide

I have a button that I want to slide out from Y position 295 to 205 when the mouse hovers/touches the button, than slides back if the mouse no longer touches the button.

This is my code, the script is on the button I want to move, I tried using RaycastHit2Ds to detect mouse position.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class SlideButton : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button button;
    float slideDownY = 205f;
    float slideUpY = 295f;
    public float slideSpeed = 5f;

    public RectTransform rectTransform;

    private void Start()
    {
        button.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonClick);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

        if(hit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("success");
            rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp(rectTransform.anchoredPosition, new Vector2(rectTransform.anchoredPosition.x, slideDownY), slideSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
        {
            rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp(rectTransform.anchoredPosition, new Vector2(rectTransform.anchoredPosition.x, slideUpY), slideSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void OnButtonClick()
    {
        // add after slider works
    }
}
```

I have also tried OnMouseEnter/OnMouseExit and OnPointerEnter/OnPointerExit but none have worked either. I haven't found anything that has solved this problem, other answers are all in different languages or not specific enough to help.

Comment: Which Unity version are you using? If OnMouseEnter does not work you are likely using the new Input System instead of Input Manager. Please confirm then it is easy to give you an answer.

Comment: @ephb depending on which event system is used `OnMouseEnter` etc would still work also with the new input system .. `Input.mousePosition` would log an error otherwise anyway

Comment: @derHugo you're right. Is it better to delete my comment or leave it up?

Comment: @WonkyMcDonkey Keep in mind with that code that once the button starts moving and you don't move your mouse with it, once it goes out of the mouse pointer's "ray", the button will return. If the location of the button is further than its width, the mouse will need to follow the button to have it move along the full path. I hope you considered this.